# php Out of Memory error when refreshing report statistics

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, memory, refresh-statistics

I have recently upgraded from Magento CE 1.9.2 to 1.9.3.10.

Since this we get the following error when Reports>Refresh Statistics is used:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1808531456) (tried to allocate
>   90 bytes) in /home/****/****/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 273

I have tried or can confirm the following:

- we are on a dedicated server
- php_memory_limit is 2048M set through MultiPHP INI editor in WHM. I have also had the error when setting it equally high in php.ini file and .htaccess
- phpinfo.php shows php_memory_limit at 2048M
- No error when refreshing statistics on a 1.9.2.4 staging version running on the same server
- No error on a fresh install of 1.9.3.10 on the same server (although this has no products or orders)
- No error when statistics are refreshed using cron
- Error still happens after disabling all extensions in local / community and using standard Magento template
- nothing in system.log or exception.log

Any new ideas I can follow up would be really useful.

Comment: Try change memory limit to -1. How many RAM have your server? Try use commands free -m or top to check memory usage

Comment: @BartZalas free - m shows `total 15877 used 4892 free 9030`. I tried changing memory limit to -1 but still got the error

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe try change ini_set('memory_limit',  in your index.php on magento root folder

Comment: Still getting the error. I have told the client to use the workaround of using cron scheduler to run the relevant cron jobs. Works fine doing it this way.